# Trying to get dynamic location (latitude & longitude) to use it in Places api

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, google-places-api

I'm trying to build a small project where we get specific nearby places (schools, hospitals, cafes etc) around 5kms radius on clicking a radio button.Here I'm trying to use the geolocation to get the dynamic location(latitude and longitude) so that I can get user current location where ever this app is used.What happening is, the map is not loading on page load while the first radio button is already checked but it is working fine when I switch to other radio buttons.

I'm not an expert in JavaScript.

Below is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        }
       #box{
        height:500px;
        width:80%;
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-right:10%;
        border:2px solid black;
       }
       h1{
        text-align:center;
        font-family:sans-serif;
       }
       form {
        text-align: center;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google Maps</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" id="school" name="places" value="School" checked onClick="load();">Schools
      <input type="radio" id="hospital" name="places" value="Hospital" onClick="load();">Hospitals
      <input type="radio" id="cafe" name="places" value="Hotel" onClick="load();">Cafes
      <input type="radio" id="atm" name="places" value="atm" onClick="load();">ATM's
    </form>
    <br>
    <div id="box">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVOCb1nOuIrbnvnTYIYTKMqs2y5ecuMi8&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=load" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript code

```
var map;
var infowindow;
var myLat;
var myLong;
x = navigator.geolocation;
x. getCurrentPosition(success);

function success(position){

  myLat = position.coords.latitude;
  myLong = position.coords.longitude;
}

function load() {
  //var hyderabad = {lat: 17.46724, lng: 78.53591};
  var hyderabad = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat , myLong);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: hyderabad,
    zoom: 12
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var place;
  if (document.getElementById('school').checked) {
  place = "school"
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('hospital').checked) {
  place = "hospital"
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('cafe').checked) {
  place = "cafe"
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('atm').checked) {
  place = "atm"
  }

  service.nearbySearch({
    location: hyderabad,
    radius: 5000,
    type: [place]
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

Comment: After the announcement yesterday, I would avoid using Google Map Api (or any google services?). See announcement here: https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html

Comment: Thankyou for letting me know.

Comment: But do you have any solution or idea for my question as of now? A small idea would also be helpful.